# How to Import features back to database

Tags: 6, updating, features

I have lots of feature modules in my site. I want to `import` it back to database for upgrade purposes. Any idea how can I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I used this patch from here - http://drupal.org/node/1014522#comment-5719202

After you patched it you can then use `drush features-import-all --yes` or `drush fia -y` to import features to database.

Answer (score 4):

There is a patch in the works for this, [Provide way to Import views/true exportables back to the database](http://drupal.org/node/663136). I have given it a quick test and upgrading seemed to work out fine, however, that particular project ended up with building a new site from scratch anyway, so I haven't used it a lot.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [features tools](http://drupal.org/project/ftools) module to import the features from code back to the database.

Note : This will really help the performance of the site.